# Need to send decimal number to smart contract for calculations

Tags: solidity, web3js, tokens

I am trying to write a smart contract which will do the below.

```
contract MyContract is ERC20{
IERC20 market;
IERC20 coin;
uint256 feesFactor = 0;
uint256 conversionRatio = 0;

    function setConversion(uint256 ratio) public {
        conversionRatio = ratio;
    }

    function getConversion() public view returns (uint256) {
        return conversionRatio;
    }

    function setFeesFactor(uint256 fees) public {
        feesFactor = fees;
    }


    function deposit(uint256 _amount) external onlyPositive(_amount) {
        

        coin.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);

        uint256 fees = _amount * feesFactor;

        market.mint(_amount - fees);

        uint256 tokens = (_amount - swapFees) * getConversion();
        _mint(msg.sender, tokens);

    }
}
```

Using web3js I attempt to pass .03 for the `feeFactor` and .04 for the `conversionRatio` using `web3.utils.toWei()`. This works and i can display these values after using `web3.utils.fromWei()`.

However my `deposit` function fails silently; the `_amount` value is also sent using `web3.utils.toWei()`.

What changes do i need to make on both the smart contract and the web3js code so that i can use decimals like `.03` and `.04` and get the deposit function to work.

Yes `approval` has been done on the `coin` before `deposit` is called.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use decimal places in Solidity, at least not at this time.
See OpenZeppellin's note on decimals [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/erc20#:%7E:text=A%20Note%20on%20decimals&text=Unfortunately%2C%20Solidity%20and%20the%20EVM,2%20tokens%2C%20but%20not%201.5%20.) and in Solidity docs [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/types.html?highlight=decimal#fixed-point-numbers)

I'd recommend calculating in whole numbers that would completely eliminate decimal places (and headache).

You could think of `conversionRatio` and `feeFactor` as percentages. e.g.: `.03` is `3%`. You would simply send the number `3` from web3js without any conversion to and from Wei. The calculation of fees would look like this:

```
uint256 fees = (_amount / 100) * feesFactor;
```

An alternative is if there is a chance for fees to go even lower. You could also think of `conversionRatio` and `feeFactor` as [basis points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_point). A basis point (bp or ‱) is one-hundredth of 1 percentage point. e.g.: `.03` is `300bp` or `300‱`. You would simply send the number `300` from web3js without any conversion to and from Wei. The calculation of fees would look like this:

```
uint256 fees = (_amount / 10000) * feesFactor;
```

*You could define the `10000` or the `100` in a constant, or you could even create a helper function to calculate percentage.*

Comment: worked for me! Thinking in terms of bps helped.